# Filtering models by values within list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Book model with a weeks_list field that stores multiple dates as strings in a list:

```
['2015-09-15', '2015-09-27']
```

In my `views.py` file I want to be able to, given a start date and end date (in the same format) filter books to be only ones that have at least one of their dates in the `weeks_list` field to be in between the given values.

e.g. if a book has the `weeks_list` field of:

```
['2015-09-15', '2015-09-27']
```

Then if I have `start_date = 2015-09-10` and `end_date = 2015-09-16` that book is accepted. Same with if s`tart_date = 2015-09-16` and `end_date = 2015-09-28`.

I can do something like this:

```
allbooks = Book.objects.filter(Q(weeks_list__contains=start_date)|Q(weeks_list__contains='2015-09-27'))
```

And if I could somehow loop it to have a Q object for all dates between the start and end dates that would work. Is that possible?

I know there's greater than/less than filters but from examples I've looked at that would work on a singular value in a field and not a list of values.

EDIT:
I've also tried this:

```
allbooks = Book.objects.all()
q=Q(weeks_list__contains='2015-09-12')
q = q.add((Q(weeks_list__contains='2015-09-15')), q.connector)
allbooks = allbooks.filter(q)
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to make the third line an "or" statement?

This is the model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
rating = models.CharField(max_length=5)
genre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
NYT_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
GR_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
isbns = models.TextField(max_length=600)
weekly_rank = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
weeks_list = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
goodreads_ID = models.CharField(max_length=25)
goodreads_URL = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
NYT_description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
```

EDIT2: I found a solution, I should have used q.or instead of q.connector. Not sure how to mark this as solved.

Comment: why don't you show us your model?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a date list("`weeks_list`"), you have a text field, you should represent dates as `dateField's` not a `TextField`.

Using `contains` in your query, you are asking if a `string` is a substring o is contained by another one.

Because that, if you query for books between this `start_date = 2015-09-16` and `end_date = 2015-09-28` , that "**strings dates**" are not substring of "`['2015-09-15', '2015-09-27']`"

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains) about **contains django filter.**